# node.js doesn't run the code

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I've created the file `gulp.js`, the code is below.

When I type `gulp sass` or `node gulp sass` or `node gulp.js`, nothing happens in node (it is supposed to print 10).

What am I doing wrong?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    console.log(10);
})
```

Comment: Name the file `gulpfile.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Change task name to `sass-task` and then try `gulp sass-task`